# Cannot use imported library in imported python file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I created a python file called dataFramePreprocessing.py with some defined functions to use in my other notebooks. In one of the functions I'm using sklearn.preprocessing. This is the function raising an error:

```
def scaleBinDF(df):
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    ...
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x) 
    ...
```

When I call the function in the other file (all the other functions work just fine), like so:

```
import dataFramePreprocessing as pr
from sklearn import preprocessing
pr.scaleBinDf(bindf)
```

this happens

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-616840fc11d7> in <module>
      1 from sklearn import preprocessing
----> 2 pr.scaleBinDf(bindf)

~/Desktop/thesis/IDSProject/dataFramePreprocessing.py in scaleBinDf(df)
     77     from sklearn import preprocessing
     78     df2 = df.drop('Label', axis=1)
---> 79     colList = df2.columns
     80     x = df2.values
     81     min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

NameError: name 'preprocessing' is not defined
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Just write the import statement outside the function as follows:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
def scaleBinDF(df):

    ...
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x) 
    ...
```

Now call this function like this

```py
import dataFramePreprocessing as pr
pr.scaleBinDf(bindf)
```

Comment: @Lobna Hisham Eldeeb Is the above-mentioned solution working as you wanted?

Comment: I've tried that, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @LobnaHishamEldeeb I can notice that you have misspelled `pr.scaleBinDf`, it should be `pr.scaleBinDF`, F capital, now see whether the program is running nicely?

Comment: Is the function running correctly, cause preprocessing has been used only over there

Comment: its working correctly, yes. If I copy the content of the function and manually run it, it works just fine, and detects preprocessing just fine